# Can't install numba on Python 3.10

Tags: python, pip, numba

Python 3.10 on Mac running OS 11.6.1

I uninstalled Python 3.9 from my machine and upgraded to version 3.10. No problems installing standard packages such as pandas, scipy, etc. However one package, epycom, requires numba.

When I enter `pip3 install numba`, I receive the lengthy error message below with the key phrase `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'llvm-config'`

Wondering if I should uninstall 3.10 and go back to 3.9?

```
Collecting numba
  Using cached numba-0.51.2.tar.gz (2.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting llvmlite<0.35,>=0.34.0.dev0
  Using cached llvmlite-0.34.0.tar.gz (107 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from numba) (1.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from numba) (58.1.0)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numba, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for llvmlite, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: llvmlite, numba
    Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/6j/xqx91xb15wl81pcnf33255bct7pzn4/T/pip-install-42hw6q4a/llvmlite_a0abee749e71467a998628e47a3a1a24/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/6j/xqx91xb15wl81pcnf33255bct7pzn4/T/pip-install-42hw6q4a/llvmlite_a0abee749e71467a998628e47a3a1a24/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/6j/xqx91xb15wl81pcnf33255bct7pzn4/T/pip-record-6u_7985j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/llvmlite
         cwd: /private/var/folders/6j/xqx91xb15wl81pcnf33255bct7pzn4/T/pip-install-42hw6q4a/llvmlite_a0abee749e71467a998628e47a3a1a24/
    Complete output (29 lines):
    running install
    running build
    got version from file /private/var/folders/6j/xqx91xb15wl81pcnf33255bct7pzn4/T/pip-install-42hw6q4a/llvmlite_a0abee749e71467a998628e47a3a1a24/llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.34.0', 'full': 'c5889c9e98c6b19d5d85ebdd982d64a03931f8e2'}
    running build_ext
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10 /private/var/folders/6j/xqx91xb15wl81pcnf33255bct7pzn4/T/pip-install-42hw6q4a/llvmlite_a0abee749e71467a998628e47a3a1a24/ffi/build.py
    LLVM version... Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/private/var/folders/6j/xqx91xb15wl81pcnf33255bct7pzn4/T/pip-install-42hw6q4a/llvmlite_a0abee749e71467a998628e47a3a1a24/ffi/build.py", line 105, in main_posix
        out = subprocess.check_output([llvm_config, '--version'])
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
        return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 501, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1842, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'llvm-config'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/private/var/folders/6j/xqx91xb15wl81pcnf33255bct7pzn4/T/pip-install-42hw6q4a/llvmlite_a0abee749e71467a998628e47a3a1a24/ffi/build.py", line 191, in <module>
        main()
      File "/private/var/folders/6j/xqx91xb15wl81pcnf33255bct7pzn4/T/pip-install-42hw6q4a/llvmlite_a0abee749e71467a998628e47a3a1a24/ffi/build.py", line 185, in main
        main_posix('osx', '.dylib')
      File "/private/var/folders/6j/xqx91xb15wl81pcnf33255bct7pzn4/T/pip-install-42hw6q4a/llvmlite_a0abee749e71467a998628e47a3a1a24/ffi/build.py", line 107, in main_posix
        raise RuntimeError("%s failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG "
    RuntimeError: llvm-config failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG to the path for llvm-config
    error: command '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/6j/xqx91xb15wl81pcnf33255bct7pzn4/T/pip-install-42hw6q4a/llvmlite_a0abee749e71467a998628e47a3a1a24/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/6j/xqx91xb15wl81pcnf33255bct7pzn4/T/pip-install-42hw6q4a/llvmlite_a0abee749e71467a998628e47a3a1a24/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/6j/xqx91xb15wl81pcnf33255bct7pzn4/T/pip-record-6u_7985j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/llvmlite Check the logs for full command output.
fishbacp@fishbacpK0ML85 ~ % pip3 install llvm
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement llvm (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for llvm
```

Comment: LLVM isn’t installed, or the program cannot find llvm-config.

Comment: Maybe try installing brew from brew.sh, and running ```brew install llvm```?

Comment: llvm isn't distributed with pip - try installing it with something like homebrew.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Installation with homebrew led to the message 

```Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/pyi-archive_viewer
Target /usr/local/bin/pyi-archive_viewer
already exists```

A later message stated 

```llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the historical issues submited on Github numba is slow in adoption of a new Python version; my guess would be that it currently does not support Python 3.10.

Reference:

https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/issues/621

https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/issues/531

Comment: @JCaesar numpy and numba are completely different things

Comment: You are quite right. I read one thing and understood another. My bad. Sorry

Comment: @AkmalSoliev  I 'm going to pursue your observation and go back to 3.9 to see if that works. This will take a while, but I'll get back to you and "accept" if it does. Thanks.

Comment: @fishbacp 3.9 worked?

Comment: It must have. I'm able to import it now and I haven't changed Python versions during the past year.

Answer (score 3):

Directly taken from the [llvmlite documentation](http://llvmlite.pydata.org/en/latest/admin-guide/install.html);

**How this ends up being a problem.**

If you are on an unsupported architecture (i.e. not x86*) or unsupported Python version for binary wheels (e.g. Python alphas) then pip will try and build Numba from sdist which in turn will try and build llvmlite from sdist. This will inevitably fail as the llvmlite source distribution needs an appropriate LLVM installation to build.

If you are using pip < 19.0 then manylinux2010 wheels will not install and you end up in the situation in 1. i.e. something unsupported so building from sdist.

Historically, this issues has manifested itself as the following error message, which included here verbatim for future reference:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'llvm-config'
```

**Things to “fix” it…**

If you are using pip < 19.0 and on x86*, then update it if you can, this will let you use the manylinux2010 binary wheels.

If you are on an unsupported architecture, for example Raspberry Pi, please use conda if you have that available.

Otherwise: you will probably need to build from source, this means providing an LLVM. If you have conda available you could use this to bootstrap the installation with a working llvm/llvmdev package. Learn more about compiling from source in the section on Building manually below. and in particular note the use of the LLVM_CONFIG environment variable for specifying where your LLVM install is.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has already pointed out numba’s LLVM-config issue. According to the GitHub links, I would try downgrading LLVM, as the GitHub link states LLVM 9 isn’t supported yet. I may be incorrect, and hope this helps!

Comment: Before upgrading to Python 3.10, I created a list of all my packages and their current versions. I didn't see LLVM, only llvmlite 0.36.0 . It seemed to get my desired package, epycom, to work I don't think I really understand the relationship between LLVM and llvmlite.

Comment: @fishbacp a bit late, but llvmlite contains Python bindings for LLVM.

Answer (score 0):

After updating llvmlite to "^0.41.0" and downgrading numpy to ">=1.25,<1.26", I was able to install numba "^0.58.0".

[This is based on github issues which @Akmal Soliev posted - I incidentally hit those before landing on this post.]